# Do I need to include a UUID in a custom BLE advertisement packet?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, ads

I am designing a small sensor circuit board with a BLE113 module. I will be broadcasting a small amount of data via Bluetooth, so I only need to use the GAP and I will not need to connect. I will be building a simple custom advertisement packet as follows:

0x02 0x01 0x1A LEN 0xFF MIL MIH {24 bytes left for payload}

where LEN is the length of the manufacturer data, and MIH:MIL is the manufacturer ID that I will obtain from the Bluetooth SIG (I just registered my LLC).

Questions: 
1) Do I **need** to include a 16-byte UUID somewhere within this transmission?? In other words, will I violate certification / standards if I keep the remaining 24 bytes to do what I want?
2) Can iOS and Android filter on things other than the UUID, such as MAC address or Manufacturer ID?
3) Will not providing the UUID cause overhead issues in iOS or Android applications?

Thanks

Comment: Is your intention to be able to listen for advertisements from your peripheral while your app is in the background, or only while the app is in the foreground?

Comment: My intention is for my app (smartphone) to scan for the peripheral continuously or quasi-continuously. The peripheral is an ultra-low-power device and I will never turn on its receiver. The peripheral is strictly transmit-only. Question is, is it mandatory that I waste 16 bytes of the peripheral's payload with a UUID?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Do I need to include a 16-byte UUID somewhere within this
>   transmission?? In other words, will I violate certification /
>   standards if I keep the remaining 24 bytes to do what I want?

You do not need include the UUID actually. You can do what you want, only if your scan apps can parse it. Spec does not prohibit you do that(even spec defined the official AD format).

> 2) Can iOS and Android filter on things other than the UUID, such as
>   MAC address or Manufacturer ID?

For MAC, yes, both of them can filter it. for Manufacturer ID, no, you need add them in AD data.

> 3) Will not providing the UUID cause overhead issues in iOS or Android
>   applications?

No.